# Applying mask to Kriging shape in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kriging, masking, density, sampling

I'm trying to apply an mask to a Kriging image for after apply a Density Sampling Network, but unfortunately I'm not getting good results.

I tried to apply on mask on Density Sampling Network and is the same that apply nothing the tool runs for all Krinhing model.

Some one have an idea how to do that using ArcGIS Desktop??